# Is it possible to install the CPU and GPU versions of tensorflow at the same time

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I am using `nvidia-docker` to access GPUs from a docker container. However, not all of our machines have GPUs and I would like to automatically fall back to the CPU version when GPUs are not available.

Do I have to build separate docker images--one for CPU and one for GPU--or is it possible to install `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu` and pick the right variant depending on whether a GPU is available?

Comment: @Stefano, can you elaborate further?

Comment: Yes, I can of course start a different image depending on whether a GPU is available but I would prefer not to maintain two separate images for each project if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GPU version of tensorflow fails to load in the container when started using normal `docker` (as opposed to `nvidia-docker`) because the library `libcuda.so.1` is missing. We managed to use the same image for different hosts in three steps:

1. Link the library stub `/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs/libcuda.so` to `libcuda.so.1` in the same directory.
2. Add the stubs directory as a search path to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` with lower precedence than the directory in which `libcuda.so.1` is mounted by `nvidia-docker`.
3. Call `ldconfig` to refresh the library cache.

If the image is used on a host without a GPU via normal `docker`, tensorflow loads the stub and places all ops on the CPU. If the image is used on a host with a GPU via `nvidia-docker`, tensorflow loads the mounted library and places appropriate ops on the GPU. Full example [here](https://github.com/tillahoffmann/universal_tensorflow).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to to take a look at the official Tensorflow [docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags/) The GPU version uses `nvidia-docker` to access the GPU.

What I've done in the past is have two nearly identical Dockefiles. The only difference in the Dockerfiles would be the FROM directive:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3
```

OR

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3
```

(you could also choose the Python2 image if you want)

Everything else would be the same, and you could even automate this, such that the appropriate `FROM` tag is set when you build the image. I have used makefiles to build the appropriate image depending on whether the host machine has GPU or not.